# I can't customize the highlight color in epubjs-rn

Tags: javascript, react-native, epub.js

I am using epubjs-rn and i wanted to select a color for highlighting a text .

I was searching in the docs and i found this code but it didn't work .

```
onSelected={(cfiRange, rendition) => {
  rendition.highlight(cfiRange, {}, (e) => {console.log(e)}, undefined, {fill: 'blue'});
}}
```

Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use fill parameter like this , that's work correctly :)

```
rendition.highlight(mcfi, {}, (e) => { console.log(e) }, undefined, { 'fill': 'gold' });
```

Comment: Thanks Meisam, this issue forced me to send a pull request to the `epubjs-rn` and that solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should set 'background: blue' instead of fill: blue